# Logo-background image not displayed (Rails app)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, background

I have config/routes.rb routed to *app/view/home/index.html.erb*

index.html.erb is linket to *app/assets/stylesheets/home.css*

It works fine and I've given style to my index site.

The problem is when I try to assign a logo as a background located in *app/assets/images/logo.png*

I try this in home.css and it doesn't work:

`body
{
    background: #FFF url('../images/logo.png') no-repeat top left;
}`

The only way to make it work is move logo.png to the stylesheets folder, but I don't want to do that.

So, how can I use a image as a background, which is in another folder?

Comment: Is that folder protected? like can you access the image like this? `http://website.com/app/assets/images/logo.png`

Comment: Use Firefox + Firebug, open the NET tab, reload the page and see of you get a 404 for the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can make it working using the [Sprockets Url Rewriter](https://github.com/carlhoerberg/sprockets-urlrewriter). It's a little gem that rewrites relative CSS urls to absolute ones. with that you can use:

```
body { background: #FFF url(logo.png) no-repeat top left; }
```

Read the [asset pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) to better understand what is going on. Or you could go for the *official* [suggestion](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-erb). Personally I prefer the Url rewriter approach. It's cleaner.